# Typescript import es6 javascript file when the target is es5

Tags: javascript, typescript, internet-explorer, template-strings

I am having an external dependency in my project that is using es6 capabilities (arrow functions, template strings etc,).

When I am importing it and trying to open it with IE I am getting errors from IE.
If I am using es6 capabilities inside my project (not from import) there are no problems there.

I can fix the external dependency but it doesn't feel the right way of doing it.
Not sure that even a pull request is the right way of doing it. Because the maintainer chooses to use es6 capabilities.

Thanks :)

Comment: What errors are they? If your `target` is `es5`, the JavaScript you import in your bundle should get transpiled.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your issue, Like which version of IE you are using? What are the error messages? Does same error message display with any other browser? If no, Try to provide a sample project which can produce the issue. We will try to make test with it to find any possible solution. Thanks for your understanding.